# gitlab does not start after power supply failure during upgrade / postgresql password

Tags: postgresql, gitlab

I'm running my own gitlab server installed like [this](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#debian):

Yesterday I did an

```
apt dist-upgrade
```

and had a power supply failure during the upgrade.
I found out that gitlab was not installed anymore. I issued:

```
apt install gitlab-ee
```

but web server does not start as it should to continue the installation. Looking at the logs, I discovered this error:

```
ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError: There is an issue connecting to your database with your username/password, username: gitlab.
```

with [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html) link, I tried to setup the sql_user_password in gitlab.rb using

```
gitlab-ctl pg-password-md5 'gitlab'
```

BUT this command asks me a password. I suspect I should provide the postgresql password but I don't remember having set it up during first gitlab installation.

Is there a default password or a way to recover?